# Operating System does not recognize installed OLE DB provider

Tags: sql-server, oledb

I have a 32 bit Windows 7 machine.

I am trying to access an excel sheet by creating a linked server in SQL Server 2012.

Below is my error.

> Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered.

The control panel's Programs And Features say the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 is available.

How do I solve this issue?

**SQL CONNECTION STRING and a QUERY:**

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server = 'ExcelServer2',
@srvproduct = 'Excel', 
@provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
@datasrc = 'D:\MyFTP\Jul19\FAILED\DCSDIM.xlsx',
@provstr = 'Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;'

SELECT * FROM ExcelServer2...DCSDIM
```

**PROVIDERS:**

[image: Image shows SQL Providers on a Windows-based machine.]

Answer (score 1):

Install the **64 - bit provider** on the server from *redis*.

Use the above-mentioned provider to invoke the SQL Server which is a 64 - bit executable.

It does not matter what provider you have on the local computer to execute SSMS.

**Office11** is the internal name for **Office 2003**.

**Office12** for **Office 2007**, and
**Office14** for **Office 2010**

After you installed the redis package for Office 2010 you need to change your code as follows:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server = 'ExcelServer2',
@srvproduct = 'Excel', 
@provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0',
@datasrc = 'D:\MyFTP\Jul19\FAILED\DCSDIM.xlsx',
@provstr = 'Excel 14.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;'

SELECT * FROM ExcelServer2...DCSDIM
```